# MODX - what can be improved?

Tags: content-management-system, modx

I'm researching MODX as a CMS and found [this interview](http://modx.com/learn/solutions/profile/brett-florio-foxycart/) with the creator of FoxyCart. 
He really gives MODX a lot of positive comments and when asked about improving MODX he pointed out the following:

> User management can be awkward, and
>   some things related to webusers have
>   never really been brought current.
>   (Newspublisher can’t handle TVs;
>   Weblogin is temperamental and not easy
>   to customize; Webusers need “TVs” for
>   additional fields.)

Can others on this site shed some light on this? What other kind of user management issues are there?

What are some areas of MODX that people think should be improved?

I'm trying to figure out whether to go with MODX or not. I've been reading a lot of positive things about it and want to make sure that I get the whole picture.

Comment: Please note, the current version of MODx (Revolution) does not separate users anymore

Answer (score 2):

Brett (Foxycart) is talking about MODX Evolution, the older codebase, and makes reference to add-ons, which are (for the most part) independently authored - so definitely improvable. MODX Revolution is the newer version, currently at 2.1 RC3. I've worked with everything from Enterprise CRMs (Tridion, Rhythmyx, Mediasurface as was) to other FOSS systems Silverstripe, Wordpress etc, and it is by far the most intelligently put together and executed of the lot.

It has some niggles - the permissions system is overly abstract and complex, it lacks some plug-and-play features, fine-tuning performance is a bit of a black art, and it doesn't have the ecosystem support of bigger players like Drupal or Joomla (or even WP). But the peer support is fantastic, the core team are committed and talented, and with a modicum of php and willingness to RTFM you can make it do almost anything with MODX.

Strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Everything can be improved, Wordpress or Drupal included, thats generalizing the topic. MODx is awesome piece of 0's and 1's which will cut your development time so much that your head will spin. Its easy to use and develop with and its fast. As far as im concerned, its web designers dream to work with. I sat give it a local spin and try playing for a day and decide afterwards.

Here are some of tuts i compiled in URL list for easy learning:
http://urli.st/3Tg

Also, Twitter #modx is also great resource to be in sync with the matter.

Hope you'll find it good!
good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've used several Content Management Platforms, and ultimately the experience has always been similar. While I can put up a site lickety-split, I have often wanted to override functionality or its output and couldn't do so without wading through large amounts of PHP files. This has always resulted in a large unsatisfactory result, because I am not lazy, unless I have to wade through others code.

When I started ModX, one week ago, the learning curve hit me like a brick. Mostly this was because it was so simple and I had been trained to deal with CMSes in complex manners. It is much more like a true Object Oriented platform (to me), and as I am an OO programmer, this fit the bill once I realized it was not as complex as I was making it out to be.

Now, in less than a week I have two nearly complete websites (a corporate software development with a shopping cart and a development blog) in less than 1/4 of the time it took me to make my original Corporate website. I'm at the tweaking style and adding content more quickly and easily than I have ever done with a CMS. I did all of the work as well. Injecting my own PHP, HTML, and CSS was amazingly easy, and I did not have to search and rely on hacky plugins to get the job done.

That being said, there are a number of ways in which ModX could be improved. The Manager uses Ajax, but most of the time it is used way too often on a full page refresh anyway. This does slow things down. The User Management is awkward, at first, and honestly should be revisited as time and community allows. The tutorials are improving, but are weak without the videos to accompany them (in my opinion). And there is a lack of variety of useful plugins, but the plugins they have are extremely useful and can be tailored for nearly any solution.

As a final note: the most useful feature is the abstraction of the properties and property sets. This allows you to override your overall site settings, for things as simple as a template or page.

FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 0):

Putting up a simple photo gallery can be a nightmare.

There is a plug in component that is very obtuse and cumbersome to implement. This is a glaring weakness when you are comparing to, say, WordPress, who are very much MODx's competition for the hearts and minds of developers.

Answer (score -1):

My 5 minutes experience with Modx (2.1.3-pl)

installed the latest (stable) version then try to run the site.

1) Error 503, site unavailable.

okay, it should show a link to the setup page but a quick search in internet showed how to open the setup manually.

2) PDO is required... well, it is starting to stink. PDO is slow

them i activated PDO in my PHP, restart apache and entered the "Connection Information" form and clicked in "Test database server connection and view collations." and

3) "Test database server connection and view collations." javascript error.. i tried with other browser and it is the same.

nuff said.

Comment: I tried with the latest build (beta) without any luck so i give up.